# Ipv4 header checksum calculation differs from Wireshark

Tags: java, checksum, ipv4

Here is my code snippet to calculate IPv4 header checksum in Java :

```
private short computeChecksum(byte[] data) {
    int end = getSizeInBytes(); // = 20
    short checkSum;
    int sum = 0;
    int wordData;
    final int checksumStart = 10; // position of checksum field inside an array

    for (int i = 0; i <= end - 1; i = i + 2) {
        // Skip, if the current bytes are checkSum bytes
        if (i == checksumStart) {
            continue;
        }
        wordData = (data[i] << 8 & 0xFF00) + (data[i + 1] & 0xFF);
        sum = sum + wordData;
    }
    int carry = sum >> 16 & 0xFF;
    int finalSum = (sum & 0xFFFF) + carry;
    checkSum = (short) ~((short) finalSum & 0xFFFF);

    return checkSum;
}
```

And this is how I form this array :

```
private void calculateCheckSum()
{
    var tmpBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate( getSizeInBytes() ).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    tmpBuffer.position(0);

    tmpBuffer.put(versionLength); // 0x45
    tmpBuffer.put(dscpEncapsulation); //0x0
    tmpBuffer.putShort(totalLength); // 1056
    tmpBuffer.putShort(identification); //0x5555
    tmpBuffer.putShort(fragOffsetFlags); // 0x0
    tmpBuffer.put(ttl); // 0xff
    tmpBuffer.put(proto); // 0x11
    tmpBuffer.putShort(checksum);

    srcAddress.serialize(tmpBuffer); // 192.168.2.200
    dstAddress.serialize(tmpBuffer); // 192.168.2.2

    System.out.println("Compute : " + String.format("0x%x", computeChecksum(tmpBuffer.array())));
    checksum = (short)0xdc5c; // from wireshark
}
```

So, for this packet I get `0xc078` as a checksum value, but Wireshark says it must be
`0xdc5c`. What am I missing? The algorithm itself seems to be rather straightforward...

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I found an issue - it's byte ordering for ByteBuffer : so, just use

```
    var tmpBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate( getSizeInBytes() 
).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
```

in the original code and it works just fine